# Domain-wide delegation of authority on Gmail in Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Can we use Domain-wide delegation of authority on Gmail in Google app engine using Java?.

http://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/wiki/GmailAndXOAUTH2